# Install a gem locally for development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm new to ruby (many years of Python experience) and want to install this [gem](https://github.com/richhollis/swagger-docs) locally to replace the existing one which I installed using `gem install swagger-docs`. I have tried everything but cannot get rails to pick up my local version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your Gemfile to use a local gem, use path like this:

```
gem "swagger-docs", :path => "/Users/name/my_swagger_fork"
```

If you want to use a git remote, you can do this:

```
gem "swagger-docs", :git => "git://github.com/user/swagger.git", :branch => "my-awesome-branch"
```

Comment: sorry for the confusion - The comment on the pull request was useless. but that line worked! that is what i was looking for - I didn't know that path parameter existed

Comment: one other question, if I want to use the forked version on github, after I push my fixes (because they havnt been merged it) - how to I specify that?

Comment: @josephmisiti `gem "swagger-docs", :git => "https://github.com/your_username/swagger-docs.git"`

Comment: updated my answer @josephmisiti - but finishingmove is right, you have the option to specify a branch if you want